# python selenium phantomjs endless scroll only work for the first page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to read some news articles using python and phantomjs.
The website I am working on using endless scrolling dynamically loads the next article when scrolling to the bottom. [Here](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2017-06-08/no-one-has-ever-made-a-corruption-machine-like-this-one)  is a sample URL.

I managed using code below to get it work to load one more article, but only one more... Can anyone help me to make it work endlessly? Or any hint what is wrong, can be improved?
Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

# Pretend to be chrome
dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
)

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)

## GET
driver.get("https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2017-06-08/no-one-has-ever-made-a-corruption-machine-like-this-one")

# print current scrollTop
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollTop')
# out: 0

# print current scrollHeight
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
# out: 18255

# scroll to bottom
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 18255)")

# print current scrollTop
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollTop')
# out: 17705

# print current scrollHeight 
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
# out: 29050
# It works! Great!

# Scroll to bottom again
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 29050)")

# print current scrollTop
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollTop')
# out: 28500

# print current scrollHeight 
driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
# out: 29050
# It's still the same, no matter how hard I try, it cannot load more... 


# According to tolmachofof's suggestion below, I tried to scroll very slowly, still no luck. :<
top = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollTop')
height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
for i in range(top, height, 100):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0," + str(i) + ")")
    print(driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollTop'))
    sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
    SCROLL_TEMPLATE = """

        var scroll_interval = arguments[0];
        var scroll_time = arguments[1];
        var scroll_step = arguments[2]

        function scroll() {
            document.body.scrollTop += scroll_step;
        }

        var _scroll = setInterval(scroll, scroll_interval)
        setTimeout(function() {clearInterval(_scroll)}, scroll_time)"""

    def scroll_page(driver, scroll_interval=0.5, scroll_time=5000, scroll_step=50):
        driver.execute_script(SCROLL_TEMPLATE, scroll_interval, scroll_time, scroll_step)
        # Script will finish before scroll if you delete it
        sleep((scroll_time / 1000) + 0.3)
```

Notes: scroll_interval is the timeout between single scroll statement.
    Scroll_time is the total page scrolling time. Scroll_step - single scroll step (px)

Comment: Please read my question, I can make it scroll, but I don't know why it only works on the first page...

Comment: You scroll works very fast. I had the same problem once. This solution helped me to paginate endlessly by decreasing a scrolling speed.

Comment: Which scroll_time param You used? I used scroll_time = 50000 in this page - it works.

Comment: I tried your code with default prams, and also tried to scroll 100px every 0.2 seconds, see my updated question. Both not work. :(

Comment: This is strange =( I executed my code as: scroll_page(driver, scroll_time=50000). In this case print driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight') is 135957